# Using Boto3 how to download list of files from AWS s3 as a zip file maintaining the folder structure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download a list of files within a parent folder my maintaining the sub folder structure.

**For example:**
Folder structure in AWS s3 https://testbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/folder2/folder3

Subfolders and files within 'folder3':

| Subfolders | files |
| --- | --- |
| 3.1 | 3.1.1.jpg, 3.1.2. jpg |
| 3.2 | 3.2.1.jpg, 3.2.2. jpg |
| 3.3 | 3.3.1.jpg, 3.3.2. jpg |

List of files to download:  [/folder3/3.1/3.1.1.jpg, /folder3/3.2/3.2.1.jpg, /folder3/3.2/3.2.2.jpg]

Is there an inbuilt function is boto3 to download the mentioned files as a zip file by maintaining the folder structure?

Note: I tried with a python package '[Aws-S3-Manager](https://github.com/anshul217/AWS-S3-MANAGER/)' but I was not able to maintain folder structure using it

Answer (score 0):

No. Amazon S3 does not have a Zip capability.

You would need to download each object individually, but you can do it **in parallel** to reduce transfer times.